# Android app crash use update at google play, but uninstall and install again, it work perfectly

Tags: android, crash

As title said.

Recently I submit an update to my apps. My client report that after updated the app from google play and run it crash immediately. But a uninstall and install work perfectly.

Now I have no clue how to fix this.

Thanks you.

Comment: did you make changes in your sq-lite database like included any new column or added a entire new table

Comment: Please inform us of the release notes of that update. So we can determine what might have caused the crash!

Comment: Any saved conflicting `Sharedpreferences` values?

Comment: Cool suggestion, I do add a new sqlite and maybe haven't consider structure different. I am checking now and will let you know. thanks.

Comment: Either you have made any change in SQlite or your SharedPrefrence may have conflict with previous saved values.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using sqlite database, and not handling that database properly that's why this is happening. If are adding/deleting some columns in database manage that via proper versioning.